# URL does not load on webview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

So I have this link
https://api1341.mr009.com/game/ptLaunchGame?agent=mobile&gameCode=art&gameType=8&sig=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjEyMTc4NDQsImxvZ2luTmFtZSI6ImRldnRlc3Q0NyIsImlhdCI6MTUzMTM5MTQ2OH0.0Ao0O9dPMWvWAHeYE1j4w5f2uLN7C32oMmVXbvTI1qQ

Which I try to run on a webview, but it doesn't work.

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

It only works when I launch the link outside the app, such as safari browser.

[image]

Oh by the way, I can only use Webview as a requirement. No WebKitView.

Comment: is above url open in Browser ? it not show anything when i try to load in browser

Comment: Try this link 
http://api1341.mr009.com/game/ptLaunchGame?agent=mobile&gameCode=art&gameType=8&sig=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjEyMTc4NDQsImxvZ2luTmFtZSI6ImRldnRlc3Q0NyIsImlhdCI6MTUzMTM5MTQ2OH0.0Ao0O9dPMWvWAHeYE1j4w5f2uLN7C32oMmVXbvTI1qQ

Comment: The link I posted can only be opened by one user at a time, if there are other people viewing the same link. It will show some sort of error written in Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by this line

```
webView.loadHTMLString(urlString, baseURL: nil)
```

That function is supposed to be used to load a local `.html` file, not a website from an URL. What you're doing is beginning to load a request using

```
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

and then immediately cancel it, by attempting to load a local `.html` file using

```
webView.loadHTMLString(urlString, baseURL: nil)
```

which obviously fails, because that's an URL, not a `.html` file.

Just remove

```
webView.loadHTMLString(urlString, baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: So I updated my code, removed the line that has loadHTMLStrin, but the webview still only showing a white empty page.

Comment: Did you implement `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol? Is delegate's `webView(_:didFailLoadWithError:)` function called? What is the error? Is the URL valid? When I open the URL in the browser,  it _does_ display an empty, white background

Comment: I get these errors in didFailLoadWithError protocol

2018-07-13 17:35:23.525426+0800 MR007[15114:238270] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2018-07-13 17:35:23.525765+0800 MR007[15114:238270] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO

Comment: When opening the URL in browser, the website displays an undefined error and empty, white background. Are you sure the URL is valid?

Comment: Yes it it the right link, I recently uploaded photos on the question, for reference.

Comment: This link can only be opened by one user at a time, if there are other people viewing the same link. It will show some sort of errors written in Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

Call delegate of webview equal to self also

webView.delegate = self
        self.webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: self.link)!))

Comment: webView.delegate = self

Comment: self.webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: self.link)!))

Comment: Please do *not* use the comments space for this kind of updates - edit & update your post instead! Also *format* your code accordingly...

Comment: Thanks sir for your suggestion